# How does hypervisor work in virtualization?

Tags: operating-system, virtualization

In virtualization, the hypervisor doesn't need to use system call?
is it always running in Kernel mode or it can run also in user mode?

Answer (score 0):

On x86, a hypervisor runs in VMX root mode. Within this mode, transitions between kernel and user mode work just as they do in VMX non-root mode (i.e., in a guest) or when VMX is off.

However, in my experience, most hypervisors always run in kernel mode.